# Use Case Diagram for Club Membership

Tags: uml, use-case

I drawing use case diagram for my club, but i not sure this is the correct way to say administrator can do anything and member only can view profile, update data only the data itself

I build diagram with gliffy, this is [my diagram](http://www.filedropper.com/test_46) and [json data](http://www.filedropper.com/test_45) (this is just another representation of the picture below).

[image: My diagram]

Comment: What format is gliffy (your json)?

Comment: it's json data with .gliffy format you can try import at [gliffy.com](https://www.gliffy.com/)

Comment: Nope. Requires registering. Please provide a format that's common.

Comment: How about [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) you can import without register

Comment: Why do you need to model user rights assignment in Use case diagram? Is it necessary? Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727404/multiple-actors-same-use-case-use-case/26730110#26730110

Answer (score 0):

In principle your drawing is ok. What is definitely wrong is `CRUD`. This is not a use case. The same goes for `Search`. A use case must have substantive and verb at least. It may have an object as well.

Another thing is `<<include>>` relation. Avoid it! What you're trying here is a functional decomposition. Use cases are synthesized. When it comes to a functional decomposition in the class design you may introduce a general package for searching or CRUD.

Comment: `a general packaged for searching or CRUD` should have been  `a general package for searching or CRUD` ?

Comment: By recommending to avoid include association do you mean that include associations should be drawn separately in a more detailed UC diagram without Actors?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal (will correct the typo) I mean that you  should simply not use `<<include>>` and/or `<<extend>>`. Rule 1: try to not use them (because we do not analyze in UC design). Rule 2: think twice; does it really make sense? Rule 3: If you have a rare case where it makes sense keep that in mind (it's a rare case!).

Comment: thank you very much for your help. . i redraw my diagram based on this conversation. . what do you think [about this](http://postimg.org/image/p9xws8ui3/) ?

Comment: @AdrianHugain Looks better, though I would still remove the includes (see my last comment). I know it's hard to understand (you should read Bittner et al. http://www.amazon.com/Use-Case-Modeling-Kurt-Bittner/dp/0201709139 ). I don't read many books but this one was an eye-opener.

Comment: @ThomasKilian is it wrong if I keep using it just to tell 'member you just can edit your data, only administrator can see other member' ? thanks again for the reference

Comment: @AdrianHugain Got your comment though you deleted it. Uffe's suggestion is also to not use the `include` and just go with the `manage` use case. N.B. the `extend` in this post is the wrong way around. Re your edited note: You can write that as a constraint to the use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches on how to draw UCs. I prefer to bind them to Business processes rather than actors, since actor is mostly just any user of the system with some access rights assigned.

In this case I agree with @Thomas Kilian that draw use cases like `CRUD` or `Update member data` is not very useful. In use case diagram you are modelling interface of your system - buttons available for the outside world (actors) to press. `Update member data` is not visible outside so why to model it in Use Case diagram?